How to merge 2 Transactions into One?
Could anyone please help me merge 2 transactions into 1?
I have followed the answer given in another thread but i cant seam to be able finish the task.
I have extracted all instructions but i cant seam to be able to extract the account keys correctly.
Can any1 please help me out?
async fn merge_transactions(
    transactions: &[VersionedTransaction],
    keypair: Keypair,
    rpc_client: &RpcClient
) -> Result<VersionedTransaction, InstructionExtractionError> {
    let collected_keys = transactions
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|swap| swap.message.static_account_keys())
        .unique()
        .cloned()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let mut address_lookup: Vec<AddressLookupTableAccount> = Vec::new();

    let instructions = transactions
        .iter()
        .map(|swap| swap.message.instructions())
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(index, signatures)| signatures.iter().map(move |instr| (index, instr)))
        .map(|(swap_id, instruction)| {
            let static_account_keys = transactions[swap_id].message.static_account_keys();

            if let Some(address_lookups) = transactions[swap_id].message.address_table_lookups() { address_lookups.iter().for_each(|table| println!("{:?}", table)) }

            let buy_key = static_account_keys[instruction.program_id_index as usize];

            let pub_keys = instruction
                .accounts
                .iter()
                .map(|index| static_account_keys[*index as usize])
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();

            Instruction::new_with_bytes(
                buy_key,
                &instruction.data,
                pub_keys
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|key| AccountMeta::new(key, true))
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
            )
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();


    for key in &collected_keys {
        let account = rpc_client
            .get_account(key)
            .await
            .map_err(|err| Box::new(err) as Box<dyn Error>)?;

        let lookup_table = AddressLookupTable::deserialize(&account.data)?;

        let lookup_account = AddressLookupTableAccount {
            key: key.clone(),
            addresses: lookup_table.addresses.to_vec(),
        };

        address_lookup.push(lookup_account);
    }

    let msg = VersionedMessage::V0(v0::Message::try_compile(
        &keypair.pubkey(),
        &instructions[..],
        &address_lookup[..],
        fetch_most_recent_block_hash(rpc_client).await?,
    )?);

    let transaction = VersionedTransaction::try_new(msg, &[&keypair])?;
    
    Ok(transaction)
}```


